# Word for the ability to solve issues with the most fitting solution

Tags: word-choice

Professionaly someone, when facing a challenge, an issue, a job that needs to be done, has different ways to face it.

What word could define the ability to pick the best approach for a given problem?

Comment: A good strategist?

Comment: consider what they are saying because a compound word expresses the meaning better

Answer (score 1):

sagacity- the quality of being sagacious (Having or showing keen mental discernment and good judgment; wise or shrewd)

acumen- The ability to make good judgments and take quick decisions

astute - Having or showing an ability to accurately assess situations or people and turn this to one’s advantage

all definitions are from oxford dictionary.

you could also say sound judgment, acute discernment or deft decision.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 'professional savviness (or [savvy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/savvy)," "perspicacity," and "discernment."

> **savvy**: the cognitive condition of someone who understands.

**perspicacity**: keenness of mental perception and understanding; discernment; penetration.

> **discernment**: the facility of discerning; discrimination; acuteness of judgment and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

> - **[expertise](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/expertise)**: special skill, knowledge, or judgment; expertness
> - **[know-how](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/know-how)**: Practical knowledge or skill; expertise
> - **[adroitness](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/adroitness)**: skill and dexterity

Answer (score 0):

[Versatility](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/versatility) would be appropriate here. Someone who is versatile can adapt to the situation and can switch between different tools and modes when necessary.